# Searching Shift/Permutation Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations

Is there a Matrix P, which does:

$$AP=A'$$
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{00} & 0 & 0\\ 
a_{10} &a_{11} & 0\\ 
a_{20} &a_{21}  & a_{22}
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$A'=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{00} & a_{11} & a_{22}\\ 
a_{10} & a_{21}& 0\\ 
a_{20} & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: How would you solve $AB=C$ for $B$?

Comment: For $A$ invertible, i.e. $a_{00}\cdot a_{11}\cdot a_{22}\neq 0$, i.e. for $a_{00}, a_{11}, a_{22}\neq 0$, you can solve the equation $AP=A'$ with $A^{-1}AP=A^{-1}A'$, i.e. $P=A^{-1}A'$.

Comment: thanks,that's no porblem to solve the equation. 
Is there a general form/matrix  which, sets the diagonals into rows for arbitary numbers and $$A^{N\times N}$$?

Comment: Try to check the conditions on the matrix $P$ by evaluating the product by hand for the entries in $A'$ this should give you a linear system of equations in variables of $P$ which you then can check for solvability.

Comment: @Bongo1234 Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, given that A is invertible we have

$$AP=A' \iff P=A^{-1}A'$$

Comment: thanks,that's no porblem to solve the equation. Is there a general form/matrix which, sets the diagonals into rows for arbitary numbers and
&&A^{N \times N}$$

Comment: I don’t understand what exactly you are asking for, could you please explain better?

Comment: There exist shift matrices and permutation matrices. If such matrix is multiplied to a vector or another matrix it does the same new range to any matrix. Now I want to have such a matrix for my problem above.